# How to let overflow-x visible and hide overflow-y

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/7y2cb/193/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
       <div class="example"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to do the opposite let the green box overflow in x without the scroll and hide the overflow in y.

I do a lot of search and nothing worked, Is there is any hack or workaround even by Javascript/jQuery ?

Comment: This feels like you already answered your question in the title. Did you use the appropriate CSS definitions by accident not knowing that they exist?

Comment: Note to self: Verify someones problem before commenting...I didn't expect `overflow-y` to affect horizontal scrolling. Anyway, you might find your answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue

Comment: In other words make overflow-x: visible without scroll and make overflow-y auto or scroll ?

Comment: @D3VELOPER .do you get solution for this problem. i also have same issue..

Answer (score 0):

Update inner class and try,

```
.inner{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```